# Usb DIsk Shows"unrecognised disk label" Unable to do dd, partition or reformat

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb-drive, storage, gparted

A Complete Noob here!

I am having trouble using my Pendrive in my arch system.
It does not mount. When I opened GParted I noticed it is taking longer to load and Pendrive was named  `/dev/sdd` in spite of `/dev/sda`. And it was showing an error flag. The error is:

> /dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label

When I tried to format it. It is taking forever, so I canceled the process.

On using `sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdd` it is showing output as:

```
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Creating filesystem with 3779198 4k blocks and 946560 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 8f872a08-2d03-442e-ac1a-6aef3d5e0b69
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208
```

So I manually did to all superblocks:

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdd
```

Yet this did not fix my problem. I don't care about the data in that Pendrive. I just want to get it fixed. Please Help me

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

### Throw it

According to my experience, this pen-drive is damaged. More exactly, the controller (between the USB and the flash memory) seems to have failed. Or it detected a critical problem and went into read-only-mode. With cheap compact devices, it happens quite often due to heat issues.

This assumes you have checked for the obvious issues including an unreliable connection (check for bent contacts, try a different computer or USB port).

Comment: Ain't there any way to fix it. As I am a minor and this was my cousin's pendrive. So then I gotta buy a new one but I don't have enough funds.

Comment: Unlikely. Hard to say for sure without detailed information about the drive, e.g. the manufacturer and the internal components. For low level-access to the drive, you may need special manufacturer-specific software which is incredibly hard to come by. Depending on the kind of error, you may be able unlock the drive, but it probably will lock up again. On the other hand, in Europe a cheap new pen-drive of 64 GB is around 10 EUR, a good one is around 25 EUR – spending that money usually is a way better deal than spending the time trying to fix an unreliable drive.